# Properties of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, classical-electrodynamics

I have the following vector field: $E=E_0(-sin(\phi),cos(\phi),0)^T$ and $E_0$ is some constant. Does anybody here have an idea what this electric field does to a metallic sphere that is in it? Thereby I mean, does it create a dipole moment or does it create a current and so on?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72021/ideal-metallic-sphere-in-electric-field)?